# Set ComboBox data source as column names

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox, datasource

I have some table from a dataSet in a reportViewer (winform), and some ComboBox. I want the ComboBox's dataSource to be a list of the table column names. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a data table in `table` variable, then to show list of it's columns in a `ComboBox` you can use a code like this:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList();
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ColumnName";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ColumnName";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also

```
 comb.DataSource = dt;
 comb.ValueMember = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString();
 comb.DisplayMember = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName.ToString();
```