# How do I create a textBox autoCompleteSource from dataset table?

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox, dataset

In my Winform I have a TextBox. I set it to "AutoComplete", and I want to know what to write in my code (c#), to set it's "AutoCompleteSource" to some column's values in a table from the DataSet.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code:

```
var rows = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
source.AddRange(rows.Select(x => x.Field<String>("ColumnName")).ToArray());
textBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
textBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
textBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
```

Just replace `table`, `textBox` and `"ColumnName"`.

Answer (score 0):

fill datasource using this post:

```
Source = dt.AsEnumerable().Select<System.Data.DataRow, String>(x => x.Field<String>("Name")).ToArray();
```

and this will suggest you

```
textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
textbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
textbox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Comment: Two things, 1) You don't need `<System.Data.DataRow, String>` in your select statement.  2) Your text box will show list of all values for `Name` column, while it's expected by OP to show a list of all column names.

Comment: I have really wanted the values. The datasource has to bee the values of specific column.

Comment: give your column name in ("Name") you will get specific column values in Source Variable

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a data table in `table` variable, then to show list of it's columns as autocomplete source, you can use a code like this:

```
var columns = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>();
var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
source.AddRange(columns.Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray());
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
```

However, using a `ComboBox` makes more sense. To see an example for `ComboBox` take a look at  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56002122/3110834).